# Possible to track twitter page views?

Tags: twitter

I want to be able to track page views on my twitter account to see what locations people are viewing from.

Is there a way with twitter or google analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for you to know anything about who reads your tweets.  You can get some basic information about the people who follow you, or the the people that you follow.  But the information you describe is not available.